# Size of $V$ to guarantee $k$-paradoxical tournament.

Tags: graph-theory, probabilistic-method

It was proven by Erdos that for any $k$ there exists a $k$-paradoxical tournament, as described here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Paradoxical_tournaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29#Paradoxical_tournaments).

I am able to show that a $k$-paradoxical tournament exists whenever ${n \choose k}(1-2^{-k})^{n-k} < 1$, but I am unable to show that $n > 2^k k^2 (\ln(2) + \text{o}(1))$ implies this, as the wikipedia article seems to say. I have tried using ${n \choose k} \leq n^k/k!$ and $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ and seem to be getting close, but cannot quite get there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think having $n > 2^kk^2(ln(2) + o(1))$ implies $k$-paradoxicity (just take a transitive tournament and you can find an undominated k-set).  What they say is that almost all such tournaments are $k$-paradoxical, which means that if the tournament is random, its probability of being $k$-paradoxical approaches 1 as $n$ grows.

Comment: @manuelaafond You are correct. I do not say that if $n$ satisfies such an equation then it is necessarily $k$-paradoxical. I am saying that if $n$ satisfies that equation then there exists a tournament on $n$ vertices that is $k$-paradoxical.

Comment: Oh my bad.  Well, if no one ever gives you a clear answer you can refer to the full proof in Erdos' paper : http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-08.pdf.  The magic starts at page 222.

Comment: Thanks! I tried looking for this paper but I couldn't find it. I guess that's a problem if you publish such an insane amount of papers.